# Prove the area of parallelogram

Tags: vectors

How to prove the length of the cross product axb is equal to the area of parallelogram determined by a and b?

Comment: What does projection of the vector $a\times b$ on to the plane of $a$ and $b$ give?

Comment: $a \times b = |a||b|\sin\theta$

Comment: Ap=|axb|. How to prove the a and b by visually, vectors?

Comment: Depends on how you've defined the cross product.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you've defined 
$$a\times b=\det\begin{pmatrix}i&j&k\\ a_1&a_2&a_3\\ b_1&b_2&b_3\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now write that out, calculate 
$$\|a\times b\|^2=(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)^2+(a_1b_3-a_1b_3)^2+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)^2$$
 and show that this squared length equals $\|a\|^2\|b\|^2-\langle a,b\rangle^2$, which is known (?) to be the squared area of the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$.